# Node.JS integration test error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000

Tags: node.js, jestjs, integration-testing, supertest

I've used [jest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest) and [supertest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/supertest) for integration tests. In afterEach section I closed server:

```
let server;
describe('/api/user', () => {
   beforeEach(() => {
      server = require('../../../app');
   });

   afterEach(async () => {
      await server.close();
   });
//some tests
});
```

But by running `npm test` I get this error:
**listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3200**

When I using just one something.test.js file, everything is OK. The problem is when I add a new something.test.js. What's wrong?

Here is the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "users",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest --watchAll"
  },
  "author": "Saeed Heidarbozorg",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "config": "^3.3.4",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-async-errors": "^3.1.1",
    "joi": "^17.4.0",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "pg": "^8.5.1",
    "winston": "^3.3.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "supertest": "^6.1.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr** in a test environment, you don't want to create an http server at all, just test your express app instance.

If you want to post your code from your `app.js`, I can probably give you a quicker fix.

In general this is the way I structure it to facilitate accomplishing the **tl;dr**:

`app.js` contains all the express-y stuff:

```
import express from 'express';
const app = express();

// ... do all your express-y stuff

export default app;
```

`index.js`is the entry point to the app that starts the server. This file **IS NOT NEEDED** during testing:

```
import http from 'http';
import app from './app';

http.createServer(app).listen(...);
```

When testing, you don't need `index.js` at all, just import your express app from `app.js` and test it:

Some test file:

```
import app from './app';
import request from 'supertest';

describe('...',() => {

   test('...', async () => {
     expect((await request(app).get('/some/route')).status).toBe(200);
   });

});
```